# A compact space has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

Proof Attempt:

Consider the open cover $\{N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)\}_{x_i\in X}$ where $N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$ is the open $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x_i \in X$. Assuming that $X$ is compact, $\{N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)\}_{x_i\in X}$ would then have a finite subcollection, $\{N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)\}_{i=1}^n$, such that $X \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$. So if $(x_k)$ is any sequence in $X$, then for all $k \in \Bbb{N}$, there exists $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ where $x_k\in N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$. Since $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real number, then as $\epsilon \to 0$, the preceding argument would still hold; that is $\forall\epsilon\gt 0, \forall k\in\Bbb{N}, \exists i=1,\cdots n$, such that $x_k\in N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$. Therefore, $(x_n)$ has at least one cluster point.

Comment: I feel like I did not really use compactness. Is this argument wrong?

Comment: You are using $n$ twice: once as the sequence index, once for the number of sets you use to cover. That is sightly confusing.

Comment: sorry about that. will change. thank you.

Comment: @Kusma: I think I have fixed it now.

Comment: It's not true in general... Maybe I didn't understood well the problem but consider $X=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb R\mid x_n\neq 0\text{ for a finite number of $n$}\}$. It's a metric space with the norm $\|(x_n)_n\|=\sqrt{\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}x_i^2}$ and it has not the BW property.

Comment: So an infinite number of zeroes are in the sequence in $X$?

Comment: @Surb your example is not compact, so there is no surprise that the BW property fails.

Comment: @supinf: Indeed, but bounded sequence won't have convergent subsequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not really correct and the notation you're using is very confusing.

Given a sequence $(z_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ you need to find $x$ such that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, infinitely many terms of the sequence belong to $N_\varepsilon(x)$.

Assume the contrary: for every $x\in X$, there is $\varepsilon_x>0$ such that $N_{\varepsilon_x}(x)$ contains only finitely many terms of the sequence: precisely, there exists $k_x$ such that $z_k\notin N_{\varepsilon_x}(x)$, for every $k>k_x$.

The family $(N_{\varepsilon_x}(x))_{x\in X}$ is an open cover of $X$, so it admits a finite subcover, say
$$
X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n N_{\varepsilon_i}(x_i)
$$
(where $\varepsilon_i=\varepsilon_{x_i}$ for readability).

Consider $\bar{k}=\max\{k_{x_1},k_{x_2},\dots,k_{x_n}\}$. For $k>\bar{k}$, we have by construction that $z_k\notin N_{\varepsilon_i}(x_i)$, which is a contradiction.

---

A comment. Such compactness arguments are highly non constructive, so you cannot hope to find a particular cluster point. At most you can prove, as done before, that assuming no cluster point exists leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding the contradiction. thanks!

Comment: If I`m not mistaken, the contradiction comes from the fact $z_k\notin N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$ after some large enough k, and that happens for any of the sets $N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$, that forms a finite cover of $X$, meaning $z_k\notin X$ for $k>\hat k$

Comment: Right. So the contradiction is due to the fact that $z_k\notin N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$ and $\{N_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ being a cover of $X$. Thanks!

Comment: @TheLastCipher Exactly.

Comment: @egreg: A follow up on your comment on non-constructibility. How do I discern propositions that have nonconstructive proofs in general? I noticed that I have a default tendency to resort to constructive proofs in metric spaces proofs and I want to save effort and time. Thanks!

Comment: @TheLastCipher There are theorems that are usually proved in a nonconstructive fashion, but could also be made constructive. It's not easy to decide when this is possible. About compactness: with this concept you can prove that every continuous function on a closed interval has maximum and minimum; however there is no general algorithm for finding them; therefore this result is highly nonconstructive.

Comment: Thank you. The existence of a general algorithm in discerning constructibility makes sense. Being able to discern plausibility of a general algorithm is a different challenge. I guess it never ends.